# Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)

Tags: perl

I have this code, and I'm getting the warning: `Argument "" isn't numeric  in numeric eq (==)` for `$id == $_`

@delete has numbers coming from a web-form(CGI request), and probably that's why perl is treating those numbers as strings. It's working fine but I don't know what to do about the warnings.

```
my @IDs =  (21, 36, 6, 7, 64, 6435, 24);
for my $id (@IDs) {
    push @insert, $id if (grep $id == $_, @delete)
}
```

I don't want the warnings. What is my best option?

I first thought of iterating over the array and calling `int` for every element, but I didn't like the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...that's why perl is treating those numbers as strings

No, Perl converts your data to a number because of the numeric equality operator `==`. When it warns about `""`, it means you have an empty string, and it will be converted to zero `0`. In other words, your `@delete` array contains an empty element.

What you probably should do instead is to use a hash:

```
my @IDs = (21, 36, 6, 7, 64, 6435, 24);
my %ID  = map { $_ => 1 } @IDs;
my @insert = grep $ID{$_}, @delete;
```

This will avoid any conversion, which can be both a good thing and a bad. For one thing, it will not convert the empty string to zero, but it also will not convert the string `" 12"` to the number `12`.

Your problem with empty strings will remain, but as long as you have no keys for the empty string, you will be ok.

Also, you should keep in mind why they are called "warnings". They are there as an indication that you are doing something that's not quite right. So merely silencing the warnings without knowing why is a very bad thing. In this case, you should specifically figure out what you want to do with empty string values. (And other possible bad values).

You can remove the empty string values from your array by doing this:

```
@delete = grep !/^$/, @delete;
```

Comment: Which is better method?
`@delete = grep !/^$/, @delete;`
Or
`@delete = grep !$_, @delete;`

Nice explanation. Cleared a lot of doubts.

Comment: Thank you. Well, `!/^$/` and `!$_` do the opposite of each other in this case. The empty string is a false value, so negating it makes it true. However, doing a true/false is also dangerous, as it can create false negatives (if zero `0` is a valid value), and false positives (e.g. letters or whitespace). If you get your values from a web form, you should probably verify them thoroughly first. In this case, the first is safer, as it does only one thing: check if the string is empty.

Answer (score 3):

If 0 is not a valid ID, use a grep syntaxt like this:

```
grep { $_ and ($id == $_) } @delete;
```

or, match if $_ has only digits:

```
grep { /\d+/ and ($id == $_) } @delete;
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick demo of your problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @insert;
my @IDs =  (21, 36, 6, 7, 64, 6435, 24);

my @delete = split / /, "1 2 4";
warn "this is ok";
for my $id (@IDs) { push @insert, $id if (grep { $id == $_ } @delete) }

warn "now get warning";
@delete = split / /, "1 2  4";
#                        ^^ note two spaces - the split will produce one empty element
for my $id (@IDs) { push @insert, $id if (grep { $id == $_ } @delete) }
```

You need validate your input only for numbers.